# Merge dataframes where df1['row']<=df2['row']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables:

```
d = {'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Month': [1,3,5],'group':['x','x','x'}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'Month': [1, 2,3,4,5], 'value': [0.8, 0.2,0.5,0.3,0.7],'group':['x','x','x']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

I would like to join on group, which in my real table is not all the same, and on rows of df2 where month is <= month in df1, SQL equivalent is join on df1.month<=df2.month with output:

| ID | Month | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.8 |
| B | 1 | 0.8 |
| B | 2 | 0.2 |
| B | 3 | 0.5 |
| C | 1 | 0.8 |
| C | 2 | 0.2 |
| C | 3 | 0.5 |
| C | 4 | 0.3 |
| C | 5 | 0.7 |

Where I will just drop the group column after the merge.

A functional but slow way to do this is to just do the join and then do df1[df1.month<=df1.month_x]. But my table is large and that would be inefficient. Is there a way to do this in one step with pd.merge or pd.join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not straightforward, but assuming you have unique rows per ID in `df1` you can perform one [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) per group and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([pd.merge_asof(df2, g, by='group', on='Month',
                               direction='forward').dropna()
                 for _, g in df1.groupby('ID')], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   Month  value group ID
0      1    0.8     x  A
1      1    0.8     x  B
2      2    0.2     x  B
3      3    0.5     x  B
4      1    0.8     x  C
5      2    0.2     x  C
6      3    0.5     x  C
7      4    0.3     x  C
8      5    0.7     x  C
```

Alternatively, using [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

out = df1.conditional_join(
    df2,
    ('Month', 'Month', '>='),
    ('group', 'group', '=='),
    df_columns=['ID']
)

# or
out = df2.conditional_join(
    df1,
    ('Month', 'Month', '<='),
    ('group', 'group', '=='),
    right_columns=['ID'],
).sort_values(by=['ID', 'Month'],
              ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   Month  value group ID
0      1    0.8     x  A
1      1    0.8     x  B
2      2    0.2     x  B
3      3    0.5     x  B
4      1    0.8     x  C
5      2    0.2     x  C
6      3    0.5     x  C
7      4    0.3     x  C
8      5    0.7     x  C
```